# How to set the width size of title bar in dialog box in mvc razor-view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have my jquery dialog box in mvc razor-view, i given the width and height of the dialog box. But, it consider only the height but not width size.Kindly tell me how to set the width size of the dialog box.i managed to do it in editing the chrome console, but i dont know how to do this in my project.Kindly tell me how to achive this.

i have my dialogbox,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
alert('ready');
   });
     function LoadSampleTest() {
alert('sample');
$("<div></div>")
    .attr('id','SampleQuestionDiv')
    .appendTo("body")
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
                .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                .css('float', 'right')
                .html('Close');
        },
        //Width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        title: "Sample Test"
    }).load("/dashboard/sampletest/");
```

With CSS class,

```
 .ui-dialog{position:absolute;padding:.2em;width:300px;overflow:hidden}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar{padding:.4em 1em;position:relative}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title{float:left;margin:.1em 16px .1em 0}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close{position:absolute;right:.3em;top:50%;width:19px;margin:-10px 0 0 0;padding:1px;height:18px}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close span{display:block;margin:1px}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover,.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:focus{padding:0}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content{position:relative;border:0;padding:.5em 1em;background:none;overflow:auto;zoom:1}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane{text-align:left;border-width:1px 0 0 0;background-image:none;margin:.5em 0 0 0;padding:.3em 1em .5em .4em}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset{float:right}.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button{margin:.5em .4em .5em 0;cursor:pointer}.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se{width:14px;height:14px;right:3px;bottom:3px}.ui-draggable .ui-dialog-titlebar{cursor:move}
```

Comment: `width`, not `Width`

Comment: its just slipped my attention there.Thank you so much.

Comment: if you can help, can you pls give solution for this, i have the close button in my dialog box, i have edited the X and made it to display text 'close', I got what i want, but, the Close text overrides with the button. which means the text 'close' is not set into the button.

Comment: Kindly tell me how to  set the width size of that button.